# Animate solid background color to image

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, background-image

I've got a set of divs and I want each of them to have different background color and while **on hover to transition to a background image** of chosen url. I have so far managed to find code for smooth color -> image transition but that requires an actual img code in HTML and I need those divs as I will be putting text in them.

Is there any chance to have a smooth 0.5s or less **transition from background color to background image with CSS?**

Comment: have you looked at css3 [`transition`](https://www.google.com/?q=css3+transition#q=css3+transition)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't **animate the `background` property from solid color to image** with CSS3 transitions.

To achieve the desired behaviour, you will need to fade in/out a layer with your solid background color. You may use a pseudo element to minimize markup for the solid color latyer layer.

Here is an example  :

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/250);
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: gold;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
div:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: +1. This. Transitions don't work on background images: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties.

Comment: Hi, thank you, the solution works as long as I dont have to put text in the actual div as it would only show after hover.

Comment: @enpe23: You could make use of the `attr()` property value on `content` on `::after` pseudo-element. Don't put text inside the div. Put your text as a value to an attribute (preferably `data-` attribute) on that div. ***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Fg78p/8/***

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started = [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/22ngA/).

You could also use JS, but it isn't necessary.

CSS

```
.changeme {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.changeme:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/DgYUsKY.jpg?1');
}
.changeme2 {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.changeme2:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/BF7aTQR.jpg');
}
```

Comment: with this technique it is not possible to have a smooth transition between the background color and the image.

Comment: I provided the OP with a starting point. The OP can take abhitalk's suggestions and learn about transitions, or the user can learn a bit about JS and jQuery. I reproduced EXACTLY the behavior of the page that OP provided.

Comment: +1 but instead of using a inner div you could use a :after element